# htaccess rewrite rules - all to index.php but server 404 for missing files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i have currently:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

and it redirect from www. to non www adress (which is good)
and redirect all missing files/directories to index.php

but i want to change it so:
user requesting missing file (domain.com/something.jpg)
gets 404 error code and not main page, it can filter on any .* or only some extensions like .png|.jpg|.jpeg

i tried removing "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f", 
but it ends with "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to
get a backtrace." :(

i tried for like 3 hours now adding some rules that match missing files and doing R=404 but it doesnt work well:(

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Replace your rules with this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the missing images before the index.php catch-all block. Add this *just after* the RewriteCond/RewriteRule of the www -> domain conversion :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .*\.(jpg|png)$
RewriteRule (.*) - [L,R=404]
```